ftp [vsftpd] gives me "500 OOPS: child died" under alpine
I have setup ftp within a fresh alpine container, and installed lftp client to test ftp with it, but it seems doesn't working giving me the following error: [500 OOPS: child died]
my setup and configuration seems ok, but not sure why it won't work.
Here is my setup:
Dockerfile:
FROM alpine:3.19

RUN apk upgrade && apk update
RUN apk add lftp vsftpd

RUN adduser -D tofaha 
RUN echo tofaha:1337 | chpasswd 

RUN \
        echo "listen=YES" > /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "local_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "write_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "anonymous_enable=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf;

CMD vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

EXPOSE 21

and then I build the image and run it using :
docker build . -t my-ftp
docker run -d -p 21:21 --name ftp-cont my-ftp

enter the container shell :
docker exec -it ftp-cont sh

then connect to ftp using lftp client:
lftp localhost -u tofaha
# Password is 1337
lftp tofaha@localhost:~>

then when I try to list or create a directory, it gives me this error:
lftp tofaha@localhost:~> ls
`ls' at 0 [500 OOPS: child died]

Any Idea?

Voting for question closing without giving any reason here in the comments is really not helpful at all, If there is something wrong in my question tell me so I can fix it, and do not do the same mistake again.

Well, It turns out that I need to add this line within vsftpd configuration:
seccomp_sandbox=NO

thanks to this post which says :

With version 3.0 of vsftpd, a new feature was introduced and it appears that this has caused problems for a few people. That feature is seccomp sandboxing and it can turned off by adding the following line in /etc/vsftpd.conf:
seccomp_sandbox=NO

edit the vsftpd.conf file, which in my case is available in this path /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf , and add the above line to it.
don't forget to restart the vsftpd service in order to apply the new configuration.
or update the dockerfile to the following :
Dockerfile:
FROM alpine:3.19

RUN apk upgrade && apk update
RUN apk add lftp vsftpd

RUN adduser -D tofaha 
RUN echo tofaha:1337 | chpasswd 

RUN \
        echo "listen=YES" > /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "local_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "write_enable=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "anonymous_enable=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf; \
        echo "seccomp_sandbox=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf;           # NOTE this new line

CMD vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

EXPOSE 21


It seems that this error occurs often when using alpine as a base image, some people add this line seccomp_sandbox=NO to vsftpd.conf file without mentioning the reason, but i found this article talking about the error link italic

@aaqlzim yeah that's really frustrating, I spent a whole day searching for the answer, even alpine Doc about ftp doesn't mention it https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/FTP, Oh Almighty God! guide Alpine creators to write good Docs, Amen
